# Dapper error : Each grid can only be iterated once

Tags: dapper

My code is as below

```
   try
        {
            SqlConnection mapperConnection = SqlAccessHelper.SqlHelper.GetOpenConnection(SqlConnectionHelper.SqlConnectionString());
            var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
            parameters.Add("@P_MarketId", marketId, DbType.Int32);
            parameters.Add("@P_Output", dbType: DbType.Int32, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

            using (var multi = mapperConnection.QueryMultiple("USP_FetchMarketRecords", parameters, (SqlTransaction)null, 1000000, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
            {
                    IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FItem> FItem = multi.Read<MarketRecord.FItem>();                        
                    IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FSubsystem> FSubsystem = multi.Read<MarketRecord.FSubsystem>();
                    objCResponseVO.addObject("FItem",FItem);
                    objCResponseVO.addObject("FSubsystem",FSubsystem);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
```

first read is fine . Second read of FSubsystem  gives me the exception "Each grid can only be iterated once". whats wrong here ?
When I traced it down in   public IEnumerable Read() method  during second read consumed  property is true  . How can i overcome from this.?

Comment: Might be helpful to see what your stored proc looks like.

Comment: My SP has just 2 select queries in it .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying data-reader is a forwards only device; by calling `Read` a second time, you *move the reader forwards to the next grid*. You should consume each grid in a forwards-only way. For example, you could re-order the statements:

```
using (var multi = mapperConnection.QueryMultiple("USP_FetchMarketRecords",
    parameters, (SqlTransaction)null, 1000000, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
        IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FItem> FItem =
            multi.Read<MarketRecord.FItem>();                        
        objCResponseVO.addObject("FItem",FItem);

        IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FSubsystem> FSubsystem =
            multi.Read<MarketRecord.FSubsystem>();            
        objCResponseVO.addObject("FSubsystem",FSubsystem);
}
```

Or you could buffer:

```
using (var multi = mapperConnection.QueryMultiple("USP_FetchMarketRecords",
    parameters, (SqlTransaction)null, 1000000, CommandType.StoredProcedure))
{
        IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FItem> FItem =
            multi.Read<MarketRecord.FItem>().ToList();
        IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FSubsystem> FSubsystem =
            multi.Read<MarketRecord.FSubsystem>().ToList();
        objCResponseVO.addObject("FItem",FItem);
        objCResponseVO.addObject("FSubsystem",FSubsystem);
}
```

Comment: reordering didnt work . just if i write  IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FItem> FItem = multi.Read<MarketRecord.FItem>();                        
                    IEnumerable<MarketRecord.FSubsystem> FSubsystem = multi.Read<MarketRecord.FSubsystem>();
 also it didnt work . However 2nd option works fine . May I know why ?

Comment: but converting to tolist will consume sometime . directly binding to same class object happens immediately.

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh right, but what is objCResponseVO.addObject doing?

Comment: that is used to send back the results to UI . I will return objCResponseVO from the method . Even if the remove those two statements it throws same error . First it was not throwing . after sometime it started throwing . Once it starts throwing even if I rebuild application and rerun the app also it will still throw the error .

Comment: @KuntadyNithesh ultimately, it is an open reader; you can't just *keep* them open indefinitely; you must either consume the data **now**, or buffer it. You can't pass it back and expect it to work. I strongly suggest `ToList()`. How much time that will consume depends on the amount of data returned. If that isn't appropriate, then you'll have to access the data much closer to the UI, i.e. write the data in two loops **immediately** after each `.Read<...>`

Answer (score 1):

I just have passed through a similar issue. Mine is Postgresql instead of SQL Server but I think it doesn't matter on this case.

Adding a ToList() at the end of the result did the trick. Hope it works for you as well.

```
            string sql = @"
                    select * from usuario where id=@id;

                    select  idarea 
                    from    areausuario
                    where   idusuario = @id;

                    select * from area;
                    ";


        var res = this.Connection.QueryMultiple(sql, p);

        var usuarioData = res.Read<Entities.Usuario>().First();
        var areasSelected = res.Read<int>().ToList();
        var areas = res.Read<Entities.CatalogoPadreSelection>().ToList();
```